# How to evaluate excited state MO coefficients using Dalton Pacakge?

Tags: computational-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, orbitals, excited-states, dalton

I need the excited state (T1) wavefunction associated with my benzene molecule, but even after trying multiple times using multiple input formats, I am not able to find the correct input to evaluate it using the Dalton Package. I'm attaching the .mol and .dal files I used below for reference.

```
BASIS
6-311++G**
Benzene using the 6-311++G** Basis set
Using automatic symmetry detection.
Atomtypes=2 Angstrom
Charge=6.0 Atoms=6
C       -1.396328944      0.000000000      0.000000000
C       -0.698164472     -1.209256337      0.000000000  
C       -0.698164472      1.209256337      0.000000000
C        0.698164472     -1.209256337      0.000000000
C        0.698164472      1.209256337      0.000000000
C        1.396328944      0.000000000      0.000000000   
Charge=1.0 Atoms=6
H       -1.241338149     -2.150060743      0.000000000
H       -1.241338149      2.150060743      0.000000000 
H        1.241338149     -2.150060743      0.000000000
H        1.241338149      2.150060743      0.000000000
H        2.482676297      0.000000000      0.000000000
H       -2.482676297      0.000000000      0.000000000
```

and the .dal file I'm using is,

```
**DALTON INPUT
.RUN WAVEFUNCTIONS
**WAVE FUNCTIONS
.HF
*SCF INPUT
.THRESH
1.0D-8
*LUCITA
.TITLE
Benzene molecule ground state + first excited state in A1
.SYMMET
 1
.MULTIP 
 2
.NROOTS
 2
**END OF DALTON INPUT
```